# How to delete specific range of records from a GROUP BY query?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with column `MediaID`. There can (and usually are) multiple records with the same `MediaID`. There is also an `AddDate` column. How can I write a query that will group records of the same `MediaID` together and for each group that has more than 10 records, order them by `AddDate` and delete all except the two oldest and two most recent records?

I've written a query that groups the records by `MediaID` and then uses `HAVING COUNT(*) > 10` which will give me the `MediaID`s that are up for deletion, and then used that as a subquery to `JOIN` back against the original table so I can see only the records that have of of these `MediaID`s, but I'm stuck on how I can filter out the records that are either the two most recent and two oldest for each `MediaID`.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MediaTest_V]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [MediaID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AddDate] [DateTime] NOT NULL
) 

INSERT INTO MediaTest_V (MediaID, AddDate)
VALUES (7, '2015-01-05T09:00:00')
INSERT INTO MediaTest_V (MediaID, AddDate)
VALUES (8, '2015-01-05T10:00:00')
INSERT INTO MediaTest_V (MediaID, AddDate)
VALUES (8, '2015-02-05T10:00:00')
INSERT INTO MediaTest_V (MediaID, AddDate)
VALUES (8, '2015-03-05T10:00:00')
INSERT INTO MediaTest_V (MediaID, AddDate)
VALUES (8, '2015-04-05T10:00:00')
INSERT INTO MediaTest_V (MediaID, AddDate)
VALUES (8, '2015-05-05T10:00:00')
INSERT INTO MediaTest_V (MediaID, AddDate)
VALUES (8, '2015-06-05T10:00:00')
INSERT INTO MediaTest_V (MediaID, AddDate)
VALUES (8, '2015-07-05T10:00:00')
INSERT INTO MediaTest_V (MediaID, AddDate)
VALUES (8, '2015-08-05T10:00:00')
INSERT INTO MediaTest_V (MediaID, AddDate)
VALUES (8, '2015-09-05T10:00:00')
INSERT INTO MediaTest_V (MediaID, AddDate)
VALUES (8, '2015-10-05T10:00:00')
INSERT INTO MediaTest_V (MediaID, AddDate)
VALUES (8, '2015-11-05T10:00:00')

SELECT *
FROM MediaTest_V mv
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MediaID
    FROM MediaTest_V
    GROUP BY MediaID
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 10
) vc ON (vc.MediaID = mv.MediaID)

+----+---------+-------------------------+
| ID | MediaID |         AddDate         |
+----+---------+-------------------------+
|  2 |       8 | 2015-01-05 10:00:00.000 |
|  3 |       8 | 2015-02-05 10:00:00.000 |
|  4 |       8 | 2015-03-05 10:00:00.000 |
|  5 |       8 | 2015-04-05 10:00:00.000 |
|  6 |       8 | 2015-05-05 10:00:00.000 |
|  7 |       8 | 2015-06-05 10:00:00.000 |
|  8 |       8 | 2015-07-05 10:00:00.000 |
|  9 |       8 | 2015-08-05 10:00:00.000 |
| 10 |       8 | 2015-09-05 10:00:00.000 |
| 11 |       8 | 2015-10-05 10:00:00.000 |
| 12 |       8 | 2015-11-05 10:00:00.000 |
+----+---------+-------------------------+
```

Minimal example showing a set of 12 records with 11 having the same `MediaID`. In this case, I would want the query to delete records of ID 2 to 10 inclusive, since more than 10 records have the `MediaID1 of 8, and records with`ID` 1, 2, 10, and 11 are either among the two most recent or two oldest records. In practice there are too many records to do this manually.

I've only gotten far enough to filter the MediaTest_V table to only those with MediaIDs that are going to have deletions, but I'm not sure how to filter out the oldest and recent records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I came up with:

Query to check results to be deleted: (col "old" is to identify two oldest records, "new" the two newest, for only those MediaIDs with a count > 10)

```
select * from (

select 
    ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by v.mediaid order by v.adddate asc) old, 
    ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by v.mediaid order by v.adddate desc) recent, 
    v.*
from MediaTest_V v
inner join (
    SELECT MediaID
    FROM MediaTest_V
    GROUP BY MediaID
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 10
) vc ON vc.MediaID = v.MediaID

) seq
where
seq.old > 2 and seq.recent > 2
```

Query to perform delete:

```
delete del
from MediaTest_V del
inner join (

select ID from (

    select 
        ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by v.mediaid order by v.adddate asc) old,
        ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by v.mediaid order by v.adddate desc) recent, 
        v.*
    from MediaTest_V v
    inner join (
        SELECT MediaID
        FROM MediaTest_V
        GROUP BY MediaID
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 10
    ) vc ON vc.MediaID = v.MediaID

) seq
where
    seq.old > 2 and seq.recent > 2

) seq on del.ID = seq.ID
```

Comment: Thanks, works great. Nice to learn more about window function uses. Also appreciate the query to check check them too before running the delete.